# Undefined variable: users (View: /home/laravel/web/laravel.swt101.eu/public_html/abonamenty/resources/views/products/edit.blade.php)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, frameworks

Firstly i made laravel relations in models and foreign key. My foreign key is user_id.

This is part of my view witch generate error:

```
            <select class="form-controll" name="user_id">

                    @foreach($users as $user)

                    <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>

                    @endforeach

            </select>
```

This is controller method for this view

```
    <?php
        
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;    
    use App\Product;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\User;
        ...
            
        public function edit(Product $product)
        {   
            $user = User::all('name','id');
            return view('products.edit',compact('product', 'user'));
        }

...
```

Comment: You don't send $users to view so you get the error

Comment: you need to edit your controller and rename the `$user` variable to `$users`

Comment: This is caused by a typo and should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'user' not 'users' in your compact function. Also your variable is defined as `$user` not `$users`. It should be like this:

```
public function edit(Product $product)
{   
    $users = User::all('name','id');
    return view('products.edit',compact('product', 'users'));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are passing `user` from controller to view instead of users..simple replace `user` with `users`.

```
public function edit(Product $product)
    {   
        $users = User::all();
        return view('products.edit',compact('product', 'users'));
    }
```

Comment: how is this answer different to the one posted here?

Comment: changed a litle bit in query

Comment: but the OP didn't ask anything about their query :)